# Notepad++ or UltraEdit: regex remove special duplicates

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, duplicates, ultraedit

I need to remove duplicates if

```
key = anything
```

but **NOT**

```
key=anything
```

the key can be anything too

e.g.
**edit_home=home** must be in place

while 
**edit_home = home or even other string** must be removed **IF** edit_home is a duplicate

for all the lines of the document

thank you

p.s. clearer example:

```
one=you are
two=we are
three_why=8908908
one = good
two = fine
three_4 = best
three_why = win
```

from that list i only need to keep:

```
one=you are
two=we are
three_why=8908908
three_4 = best // because three_4 doesn't have a duplicate
```

I found a method to do it, but I would need a better search list support by regex or a plugin or a direct regex (which I don't know).

That is: I have two files to compare.

One has the full keys, the other has incomplete.

I merge in a new file all the keys from the first file with those ones of the second, in groups (because the keys are in groups e.g. many keys titled one, many titled two and so on...). Then I regex replace all the keys in the new file by

```
find (.*)(\s\=\s) replace with \1\=
```

So they all become `key=anything`

Then I replace everything after = with empty to isolate the keys.

Then remove the duplicates.

At this point I have trouble to do something like

```
^.*(^keyone\b|^keytwo\b|^keythree\b).*$
```

to find all those keys in the document I need. So from that I can select all and replace with the correct keys.

Why? Because in this example the keys are 3 only BUT indeed the keys are many and the find field breaks at a certain point.

How to do it right?

Update: I found Toolbucket plugin which allows to search for many strings, but another issue is that in addition to duplicate, I also have to remove the original.

That is, if I find 2 times the same key "one" I have to remove all the lines containing one.

Comment: It would help to see a sample portion of the document, as well as the intended result. It's unclear how "duplicates" factor into this.

Comment: Do you mean duplicates on the same line? Or duplicates anywhere in whole document?

Comment: updated with a clearer example...thanks

Comment: duplicates in all the current document.
Keys must not have duplicates and only those with key=anything have to rest...

Comment: So if "one=x" was in the original too at the end, it would stay?

Comment: only 1 duplicate of the same key can be there in the document... so if there are one=x and one = y ONLY one=x must be present

Comment: IF one=x + one = x OR even one = y
ONLY one=x would stay at the end, key here is one

Comment: I doubt if regex is a good choice here.  Just write a little script, that should be much much easier than using regex.

Answer (score 0):

`Ctrl` + `F`

**Find** tab

**Find what**: `^.*\S=\S.*$`

**Find All in Current Document**

Copy result from result window to a new window (the list of Line 1: Line 2: Line 3: ...)

`Ctrl` + `F`

**Replace** tab

(the following will remove the leading "Line number:" from every line)

**Find what**: `^.*?\d:\s`

**Replace with**: Empty

Comment: first of all, "find all in current document" returns an unuseful window 'cause it adds Line 1: Line 2: Line 3: and so on in front of each line... so i can't easily select all, then your second regex does nothing...now update the question to make it clearer...anyway thanks

Comment: When I wrote "Copy result from result window to a new window" I meant to copy that list of Line 1: ... list to a new document and invoke the second regex on them... I've updated the answer to better reflect that

Comment: i think that you haven't clear what i need. updated the question to let you understand...

Answer (score 0):

ok, after all that i wrote, one solution could be (therefore, once i have the merged keys)

```
(?m)^(.*)$(?=\r?\n^(?!\1).*(?s).*?\1)
```

with this i can mark/highlight all the duplicated keys :-) so then i can manage those only, removing them from the first list and adding what remains to the second file...

If someone has a solution with a direct regex will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Here is a commented UltraEdit script for this task.

```js
// Note: This script does not work for large files as it loads the
// entire file content into very limited scripting memory for fast
// processing even with multiple GB of RAM installed.

if (UltraEdit.document.length > 0)  // Is any file opened?
{
   // Define environment for this script and select entire file content.
   UltraEdit.insertMode();
   UltraEdit.columnModeOff();
   UltraEdit.activeDocument.selectAll();

   // Determine line termination used currently in active file.
   var sLineTerm = "\r\n";
   if (typeof(UltraEdit.activeDocument.lineTerminator) == "number")
   {
      // The two lines below require UE v16.00 or UES v10.00 or later.
      if (UltraEdit.activeDocument.lineTerminator == 1) sLineTerm = "\n";
      else if (UltraEdit.activeDocument.lineTerminator == 2) sLineTerm = "\r";
   }
   else  // This version of UE/UES does not offer line terminator property.
   {
      if (UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection.indexOf(sLineTerm) < 0)
      {
         sLineTerm = "\n";          // Not DOS, perhaps UNIX.
         if (UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection.indexOf(sLineTerm) < 0)
         {
            sLineTerm = "\r";       // Also not UNIX, perhaps MAC.
            if (UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection.indexOf(sLineTerm) < 0)
            {
               sLineTerm = "\r\n";  // No line terminator, use DOS.
            }
         }
      }
   }

   // Get all lines of active file into an array of strings
   // with each string being one line from active file.
   var asLines = UltraEdit.activeDocument.selection.split(sLineTerm);
   var nTotalLines = asLines.length;

   // Process each line in the array.
   for(var nCurrentLine = 0; nCurrentLine < asLines.length; nCurrentLine++)
   {
      // Skip all lines not containing or starting with an equal sign.
      if (asLines[nCurrentLine].indexOf('=') < 1) continue;

      // Get string left to equal sign with tabs/spaces trimmed.
      var sKey = asLines[nCurrentLine].replace(/^[\t ]*([^\t =]+).*$/,"$1");

      // Skip lines beginning with just tabs/spaces left to equal sign.
      if (sKey.length == asLines[nCurrentLine].length) continue;
      var_dump(sKey);

      // Build the regular expression for the search in all other lines.
      var rRegSearch = new RegExp("^[\\t ]*"+sKey+"[\\t ]*=","g");

      // Ceck all remaining lines for a line also starting with
      // this key string case-sensitive with left to an equal sign.
      var nLineCompare = nCurrentLine + 1;
      while(nLineCompare < asLines.length)
      {
         // Does this line also has this key left to equal
         // sign with or without surrounding spaces/tabs?
         if (asLines[nLineCompare].search(rRegSearch) < 0)
         {
            nLineCompare++;   // No, continue on next line.
         }
         else  // Yes, remove this line from array.
         {
            asLines.splice(nLineCompare,1);
         }
      }
   }
   // Was any line removed from the array?
   if (nTotalLines == asLines.length)
   {
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();  // Cancel the selection.
      UltraEdit.messageBox("Nothing found to remove!");
   }
   else
   {
      // If version of UE/UES supports direct write to clipboard, use
      // user clipboard 9 to paste the lines into file with overwritting
      // everything as this is much faster than using write command in
      // older versions of UE/UES.
      if (typeof(UltraEdit.clipboardContent) == "string")
      {
         var nActiveClipboard = UltraEdit.clipboardIdx;
         UltraEdit.selectClipboard(9);
         UltraEdit.clipboardContent = asLines.join(sLineTerm);
         UltraEdit.activeDocument.paste();
         UltraEdit.clearClipboard();
         UltraEdit.selectClipboard(nActiveClipboard);
      }
      else UltraEdit.activeDocument.write(asLines.join(sLineTerm));

      var nRemoved = nTotalLines - asLines.length;
      UltraEdit.activeDocument.top();
      UltraEdit.messageBox("Removed " + nRemoved + " line" + ((nRemoved != 1) ? "s" : "") + " on updated file.");
   }
}
```

Copy this code and paste it into a new ASCII file using DOS line terminators in UltraEdit.

Next use command **File - Save As** to save the script file for example with name **RemoveDuplicateKeys.js** into **%AppData%\IDMComp\UltraEdit\MyScripts** or wherever you want to have saved your UltraEdit scripts.

Open **Scripting - Scripts** and add the just saved UltraEdit script to the list of scripts. You can enter a description for this script, too.

Open the file with the list, or make this file active if it is already opened in UltraEdit.

Run the script by clicking on it in menu **Scripting**, or by opening **Views - Views/Lists - Script List** and double clicking on the script.